# Equation rendering is not as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angular, katex

I'm playing around with equations, which I'm trying to render in LaTeX using [KaTeX](https://katex.org/).

I think I'm doing something wrong, because the HTML render is not like it is shown on the demo output on KaTeX website.

For example, for the LaTeX code:

```
-1\times\frac{i\times\sqrt{64}}{8}\times\sqrt{i^2}
```

This is what I've got:

[image]

This is what's expected according to the KaTeX demo:

[image]

In both case, it is the HTML rendering and not the MathML one.

I'm pretty sure I'm not using something correctly, but I can't point at the problem.

Any clue would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I eventually found what was my mistake.

I just forgot to import katex stylesheet...

A simple `@import '~katex/dist/katex.css';` in my `styles.css` did the trick.